# Switch between a preview template and an edit template using directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use ng-repeat to print out posts from a feed:

```
<div ng-ctrl="feedCtrl">
    <feedpost ng-repeat="post in posts"></feedpost>
</div>
```

And here is the feedpost directive:

```
.directive('feedpost', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/views/feed/post.html'
    }
}
```

And here is a simplified version of the feed post template:

```
<div class="feedPost">
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    <div>
        <div class="file" ng-repeat="file in post.files">{{ file.name }}</div>
    </div>
    <a ng-click="editPost()">Edit</a>
</div>
```

What I would like to achieve is to have the post.html template be replaced with an editPost.html template containing a form to edit the post when the edit link is clicked (and vice versa when the edit is submitted).

I've been Googling around for a while trying to find a solution. All I could find was people using hidden forms and ng-show/hide, but I'm reluctant to have a feed filled with hidden forms if there is a better way to do it.

I thought about chnaging the `<feedpost>` element to a `<editfeedpost>` when the edit link is clicked, but that doesn't seem right (and I'm not sure how to gou about doing it in angular anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Educated guess here, not certain it'll work.

You could have your feedpost use an ng-switch statement, and then set scope level variable on each post to determine which template to include. I used ng-switch because it only includes the html if the switch condition is met.

This would be your directive template:

```
<ng-switch on="post.viewMode">
    <ng-switch when="post" ng-include="'/views/feed/post.html'">
    <ng-switch when="edit" ng-include="'/views/feed/edit.html'">
</ng-switch>
```

This would be post.html. Note that I use $parent to account for ng-include creating a new scope.

```
<div class="feedPost">
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    <div>
        <div class="file" ng-repeat="file in post.files">{{ file.name }}</div>
    </div>
    <a ng-click="post.$parent.viewMode = 'edit'">Edit</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't think of using ng-switch.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit return and it somehow took me longer than 5 mins to finish my comment... It works. I just changed your implementation to use directives instead `<feedposteditor ng-switch-when="post.editMode"></feedposteditor>` and I created a `toggleEditMode` function in the PostCtrl so that I can just call that with ng-click to switch between the modes. Thanks for your help.